# CKEditor and IMCE modules not working fine

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am having problems trying to integrate IMCE with CKEditor.

I have followed readme.txt instructions from IMCE module but it still not working.

- I have set IMCE on File browser type (Link dialog window)
- I have tried to take image from server but I get a window with my website inside.

Can anyone help me?

I am working in local with XAMPP on a macbook pro "Sierra". I don't know if it can be helpful

Here some screenshots that may help.

> [image: Screenshot of CKEditor configuration]

> [image: Trying to take image from server]

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: You might have a permissions issue. Do you get any errors or messages in the watchdog under admin/reports/dblog?

Comment: Seems that it's a problem with permissions, with first user created on install Drupal I can upload images, but with other user with role administrator and all the IMCE and CKeditor roles activated I still get errors.

Comment: IMCE has media profiles management here: admin/config/media/imce and user-1 has all permissions... try to compare the user-1 with the other users and see what might be causing this...